# UIAlertView not responding

Tags: ios, objective-c, uibutton, uialertview

I have set Delegate :
`@interface FJLockFaceViewController ()<UIAlertViewDelegate>`

and void :

```
- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex
{
    if (alertView.tag == 1)
    {
       if (buttonIndex == 1)
       {
          NSLog(@"YES");
          [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"Login" sender:nil];
       }
    }
    else  if (alertView.tag == 2)
    {
        if (buttonIndex == 1)
        {
           NSLog(@"NO");
           [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"Retry" sender:nil];
        }
    }
}
```

Also my IBAction :

```
- (IBAction)Success:(UIButton *)sender
{
   UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"WELCOME!"
                                                   message:nil
                                                  delegate:self
                                         cancelButtonTitle:nil
                                         otherButtonTitles:@"Continue",nil];
   alert.tag = 1;
   [alert show];
}

- (IBAction)Fail:(UIButton *)sender
{
   UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Failed to Recognize User"]
                                                   message:nil
                                                  delegate:self
                                         cancelButtonTitle:nil
                                         otherButtonTitles:@"Try Again",nil];
   alert.tag = 2;
   [alert show];
}
```

But the button on UIAlertView is not responding, what did I do wrong?

Comment: What you mean by not responding ?

Comment: replace code with if(buttonIndex == 0)

Comment: which xcode version are you using?

Comment: @Rushabh I changed my index to 0 and it worked ! Thank you so much!

Comment: What is happening? Button do not click OR Button clicks and coming in the delegate function and do not goes in expected condition?

Comment: Instead of `index == 0` or `index == 1`, you may try `[alertView firstOtherButtonIndex] == buttonIndex`

Comment: No need to check for index at all since there are no multiple buttons in his Alerts. He should just check for tags and be done with it.

Answer (score 1):

As @Rushabh said, You have only one button in `UIAlertView`. That's why you should use this block:

```
- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex {
if (alertView.tag == 1) {
    if (buttonIndex == 0) {
        NSLog(@"YES");
        [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"Login" sender:nil];
    }
}else  if (alertView.tag == 2) {
    if (buttonIndex == 0) {
        NSLog(@"NO");
        [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"Retry" sender:nil];
    }
}
}
```

Since the button tapped is on index 0, not 1, the code doesn't get inside the success of if condition. And I must say you would have known that had you used proper breakpoints to know what was causing the issue. Also since there are no other buttons in your `UIAlertView`, why are you even bothering to check for button index? Just check the tags and have with it.